# OpenESB: (How) Can I deploy an externally-created BPEL process?

Tags: netbeans, soa, bpel, enterprise-architect, open-esb

I have downloaded the **OpenESB-Netbeans** bundle.
It can be used to create and deploy (run) **BPEL** processes.

But what I need is to be able to deploy an **externally**-created BPEL process.

My external process comes from **Enterprise Architect** and consists just of two files `.bpel` and `.wsdl`.

**EDIT**:
**Enterprise Architect** sadly only creates BPEL 1.x files, which are not supported by Netbeans' BPEL editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a bpel module in netbeans into which you can put your bpel file and the wsdl. Once done make sure there are no errors.

Then create a composite application project to which you add your bpel module project. You can then deploy that.

Comment: Sadly, **it didn't work**, because Netbeans+OpenESB need **BPEL-2.0** standard, while the current version of Enterprise Architect supports only **BPEL-1.1**.